# @tf.custom_gradient in eager mode with complicated arguments

Tags: tensorflow

I have a fonction for which I need to define a custom gradient, but I need the gradients only with respects to one of the parameters that is a nested list of tensors.
I've recreated a simple example describing my problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python import tfe
tf.enable_eager_execution()

@tf.custom_gradient
def function(const, var, iw):
    loss = const["next"]*(var[0] + tf.reduce_sum(var[1])*const["prev"] + iw*var[2])

    def grad(dy):
        return [0.0, dy * 2.0 * var, 0.0]
    return loss, grad


grads = tfe.implicit_value_and_gradients(function)
var = [tf.convert_to_tensor(13.0), [tf.convert_to_tensor(6.0), tf.convert_to_tensor(7.0)], tf.convert_to_tensor(3.0)]
const = {"next": 3.0, "prev": 2.0}
iw = 0.1
loss, grads_and_vars = grads(const, var, iw)
print(loss, grads_and_vars)
```

Here I need the gradients of `function` only with respect to `var`, which is a nested list (representing costs on a lattice structure, computed by an RNN).

I have two issues:
First: tensorflow complains about that one of the parameter is a `dict`:
 `ValueError: Attempt to convert a value ({'next': 3.0, 'prev': 2.0}) with an unsupported type (<class 'dict'>) to a Tensor.`

Second: If I get rid of this parameter somehow, I get more issues with the nested list:
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [] != values[1].shape = [2] [Op:Pack] name: packed/`

What I'd like to be able to do is to return a nested list with the same structure as `var` for the gradient of `function` with respect to `var`.

Comment: Hi Pafnouti, by definition a tensor is an array of more than two axes. In your case you are trying to force a dict to become an array, which cannot happen. Why don't you try two tensors: tfe.Variable(3.0,name="next") tfe.Variable(2.0,name="prev")?